# Codeigniter - Text helper to use in storing japanese characters in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, text

I have a form where a text should be converted to japanese characters, I am manually converting the text into japanese and stores it in the database. However, characters are not translated as it should be? My question is what text helper should i use to store japanese characters in the database and output it right in the web? Also, what method should i use to convert submitted text in a form and convert it into japanese, maybe just like google translate?

Comment: So the user gives input in English and you want to convert and store that value as Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google translate API ([documetation](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started?csw=1)). Its a paid service, no free quota ([See here](https://cloud.google.com/console/tos?id=translate)). I'm not sure how much accuracy it will give you.